# Unknown tree/shrub with star shaped seedpods, white flowers

Tags: identification, trees, shrubs, seeds

No one can seem to work out what kind of tree/shrub this is. The seedpods are a distinctive star shape, it has smooth green leaves and it has small white flowers in spring/summer. Growing in the UK. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: what part of the world is the plant growing in?  Please add this to your question

Comment: @Sarah Jane Possibly Lignum vitae, I have seen it purple with white stamens.

Comment: @Rob unlikely to be a tropical hardwood growing outside in the UK

Comment: My first thought was some sort of _Illicium sp._ but they usually have more lobes to their fruits

Comment: Also _Illicium_ tend to be evergreen. Do the pods split to reveal brightly coloured seeds? If so could be some sort of _Euonymus_

Comment: @Georgeofalltrades Actually, Guaiacum sanctum is a very slow growing hardwood that could easily be mistaken for a shrub when young and it grows all over Europe.

Comment: @Rob OP states flowers are small and white, _Guaiacum sanctum_ are showy and purple. Seedpods not quite right either. It is only borderline frost hardy (USDA 10-12) and so would not persist in the UK. I have not encountered it, not even in Cornwall.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is *Exochorda x macrantha* 'The Bride' hybrid, also known as [pearl bush](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Exochorda). It has white flowers, and seedpods like [this](http://penelopehellyer.blogspot.com/2014/03/exochorda-x-macrantha-bride.html) here.